# How do I structure the relationship between my Position model and my Player model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Player` model, who `has_many :positions`. Think of a player as someone playing sports, where they can play multiple positions on the field (i.e. forward, left wing, defensive midfield).

I can't quite figure out how to model this, from a DB perspective.

Initially my `Position.rb` looked like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: positions
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  position_type :integer
#  player_id    :integer
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player

  enum position_type: { goalkeeper: 0, center_back: 1, left_back: 2, right_back: 3, left_wing_back: 4, right_wing_back: 5, defending_midfielder: 6, central_midfielder: 7, attacking_midfielder: 8, left_midfield: 9, right_midfield: 10, left_wing: 11, right_wing: 12, center_forward: 13 }
end
```

But that feels wrong.

Should I do something like just have a regular `Position` model, then just create unique records for each of the positions, then have a HABTM relationship between the two?

Is this the one situation where HABTM is appropriate? I haven't used such a relationship in a while.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem** **which helps in managing multiple roles** for same model say Player. Define the roles and associate to player. Refer official documentation.

In case there are some restrictions like specific player can play at only 2 or 3 positions. **You can use [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) where authorization can be handled.**

If you don't want to go with gems, go ahead and create a new model for position and player association. Something like the below code, further optimisations can be done on same.

```
  class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Define a table with the values present in enum which should be mostly one time operation.
  end

  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :player_positions, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :positions, :through => :player_positions
  end

  class PlayerPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :position
    #this table will have player_id and position_id as attributes
    #Also have a active_position_id since one player can have only one position at a certain time when the game is played.
  end
```

You will end having one player have multiple entries related to position in the player position table. To manage the realtime position of a player, **have a active_position_id since one player can have only one position** at a certain time when the game is played.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a many to many join table:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_postitions
  has_many :postitions, through: :player_postitions
end

class PlayerPostition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :position
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum position_type: { goalkeeper: 0, center_back: 1, left_back: 2, right_back: 3, left_wing_back: 4, right_wing_back: 5, defending_midfielder: 6, central_midfielder: 7, attacking_midfielder: 8, left_midfield: 9, right_midfield: 10, left_wing: 11, right_wing: 12, center_forward: 13 }
  has_many :player_postitions
  has_many :players, through: :player_postitions
end
```

Here we are using `has_many` with the `through` option instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

The core difference between `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that the later is direct without a intervening model. That is quite limiting since you cannot query the join table directly or attach metadata to the relation. For example you could not create a three way join:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_postitions
  has_many :postitions, through: :player_postitions
  has_many :games, through: :player_postitions
end

class PlayerPostition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :position
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_postitions
  has_many :players, through: :player_postitions
  has_many :positions, through: :player_postitions
end
```

Another important difference is the naming of the join table. For HABTM you would name the join table `players_postions` and `player_postions` for `has_many through:` due to the way that ActiveRecord does constant lookup based on the relation name. `has_many :players_postitions` would cause AR to lookup `Players::Postitions` unless you specify the class name.

- http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Answer (score 1):

You already got two great answers, but I'll add an alternative. The following approach will work fine, if you don't need any code in your `Position` model. You don't need the model at all, in that case.

You can add an extra `positions` column in your database to store the positions of each player. Depending on the database server you use, you may be able to use a native array column type (and index), and also write specialized queries. PostgreSQL, for example, supports [array columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html) and has special [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html) that allow you to find the rows you need. I'm not sure if/how other database servers support these features.

Rails supports [array columns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) when using the pg database adapter. Here's how you create a player record:

```
Player.create(name: 'John Doe', positions: %w(center_back left_back))
```

Here's how you find players who can be center backs (and any other position):

```
Player.where("'center_back' = ANY(positions)")
```

If you want to take this further, you could also add scopes to your `Player` model, to hide the required SQL functions:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_position, -> (position) { where("'#{position}' = ANY(positions)") }
end

Player.for_position('center_back')
```